# Moving new drive volume out of /media

Tags: partitioning, ubuntu-9.10, mount

I have the following filesystem:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/sda1              33G  2.7G   29G   9% /
udev                 1007M  232K 1007M   1% /dev
none                 1007M  244K 1007M   1% /dev/shm
none                 1007M  292K 1007M   1% /var/run
none                 1007M     0 1007M   0% /var/lock
none                 1007M     0 1007M   0% /lib/init/rw
none                   33G  2.7G   29G   9% /var/lib/ureadahead/debugfs
/dev/sdb1             137G   69M  137G   1% /media/New Volume
```

I want the `/media/New Volume` to become part of `/`. Does anyone know how I can do that without using `gparted` etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Add a new entry for it in `/etc/fstab`. See the `fstab(5)` man page for details.